# HTTP Error 401 at accessing Socialcast API

Tags: java, http-authentication, http-status-code-401, http-error

I receive 401 Unauthorized when trying to connect to Socialcast API (Demo).
This is my code:

```
ClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new BasicClientConnectionManager();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager);
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("myproxy", myport);
    client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

    Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator("emily@socialcast.com", "demo"));

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://demo.socialcast.com/api/authentication.xml".toString());
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
    int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        System.out.println(httpResponse.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println(httpResponse.toString());
    }
```

**Error message**:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Server: nginx/1.0.14, Date: Thu, 17 Jan 2013 13:59:40 GMT, 
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, 
Connection: keep-alive, Status: 401, X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.11, 
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Socialcast Email address/Password", X-Frame-Options: sameorigin, X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1, 
Cache-Control: no-cache, Set-Cookie: _socialcast_session=533602fb85f83dda3b9198a585f79961; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, 
Set-Cookie: sct=2657f8e636d2c321e83748fae9223a994b2f5b7a1720d2282f7a; path=/; expires=Sat, 17-Jan-2015 13:59:40 GMT, 
X-Request-Id: ee136acfaba474d376ecb1caceb6c055, X-Runtime: 0.010022, X-Rack-Cache: miss]
```

What is wrong about it?

Comment: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html  might help

Comment: that doesn't help me, sry. I do know what this error means, but I don't know why it occurs since the credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, this code works:

```
    System.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
    System.setProperty("proxyHost", "myproxy");
    System.setProperty("proxyPort", "myport");

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            System.out.printf("url=%s, host=%s, ip=%s, port=%s%n", getRequestingURL(),
                    getRequestingHost(), getRequestingSite(), getRequestingPort());

            return new PasswordAuthentication("emily@socialcast.com", "demo".toCharArray());
        }
    });

    URL url = new URL("https://demo.socialcast.com/api/users");
    System.out.println(new Scanner(url.openStream()).useDelimiter("\\Z").next());
```